# Google Mock, What will happen if a matcher fully override the previous one?

Tags: googlemock

I am working on Google Mock and considering this syntax:

1. EXPECT_CALL(Example, example(_,_,false)).WillOnce(action);
2. EXPECT_CALL(Example, example(_,_,_)).WillRepeatedly(action);

According the doc, google mock will search the matcher in reverse older. So Will the first statement throw an exception?  In the doc, it said the first one would be shadowed. Does it mean that GoogleMock will not generate anything for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, expectation (1) will never be met and the test will fail. Since googlemock searches expectations in reverse order, all calls to Example.example() will match (2), and (1) will never be satisfied.